# Quitar dia de la semana del CalendarView (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, date, app

Ya tengo mi calendario implementado en la app movil, pero necesito que solamente muestre y pueda seleccionar los días de la semana laborales (Lunes, Martes, Miércoles, Jueves, Viernes y Sábado).

Ya que el calendario guarda fechas para pedidos, pero los dias domingos no son laborales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que propiedad se tiene que modificar para delimitar los dias de las semanas
o talves en el XML de la vista se pueda modificar esa parte pero la verdad desconozco como.

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask],saludos

Answer (score 1):

```
setFechaDeseada();
    fechaRecoleccion.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()+24*60*60*1000);
    fechaRecoleccion.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener()

    {



        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            fechaDeseada =year + "," + (month +1) + "," + dayOfMonth;
            fechamostrada = "Fecha Seleccionada: "+ dayOfMonth + " , 0" + (month +1) + " , " + year;
            //Toast.makeText(fechaRecoleccion.getContext(), fechamostrada, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // linea para mostrar mensjae en cualquier fecha seleccionada.

            //IF para condicionar el calendario y no deje seleccionar los dias domingos ()
            Calendar checkCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            checkCalendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            if(checkCalendar.equals(lastSelectedCalendar))
                return;
            if(checkCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                Toast.makeText(fechaRecoleccion.getContext(), "Seleccione otra fecha que no sea en domingo!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //linea para mostrar mensaje en domingos
                enviarRecoleccionBtn.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
                lastSelectedCalendar = checkCalendar;


        }
    });
```

Aquí esta el resultado de este código, es la solución mas sencilla que encontré, igual si se quiere quitar otras semanas pues hay que modificar esa condición o sino el calendarview. Es la única solución que he encontrado en los foros en ESPAÑOL.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Correcion**
Creo no es necesario el primer IF, quitando ese mismo y agregando la Habilitacion del boton (Esa parte se me olvido XD) quedaria asi el IF:

  if(checkCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                    Toast.makeText(fechaRecoleccion.getContext(), "Seleccione otra fecha que no sea en domingo!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //linea para mostrar mensaje en domingos
                    enviarRecoleccionBtn.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                    enviarRecoleccionBtn.setEnabled(true);


todo esta muy bien

Comment: No se si esto es una respuesta a ti mismo o una ampliación de la pregunta. Si es una ampliación de la pregunta puedes editarla pulsando sobre el enlace a pie de pregunta que pone **Editar**.  Si es una respuesta deberias agregar el comentario con los cambios que has hecho a la misma de igual forma, pero a pie de la respuesta está el enlace **Editar** para ello. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

estuve revisando una solución usando el CalendarView pero no logré encontrar hasta el momento una solución con ese elemento. Aun así, pude encontrar otra manera de realizarlo, esta es a través de una librería.

A continuación mostraré unas imágenes para explicar como funciona:

[image: Capturas]

En esta manera de hacerlo, desplego el calendario con un evento en un botón, luego podrás elegir los días y aquí si se pueden bloquear los días que tu consideres necesarios (Domingos por ejemplo).
Luego la fecha obtenida la podrás usar para tu propósito, en mi caso solo la mostré en un Toast.

Código:

Primero debes hacer la implementación:

```
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'
```

Te dejo el [enlace del proyecto de GitHub](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) donde podrás conocer mas esta implementación

Luego de esto, en la actividad donde necesitas poder el calendario, debes poder la implementacion `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` en la clase, es decir:

```
public class tuActividad extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
```

este `implements` te pedirá implementar un método:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int Year, int Month, int Day) {
    String date = "Fecha Elegida: " + Day + "/" + (Month + 1) + "/" + Year;
    Toast.makeText(tuActividad.this, date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Este Toast definido acá dentro será el que mostrará cuando seleccionemos una fecha.

Una vez tengamos esto definimos como globales las variables a necesitar:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
int Year, Month, Day;
Calendar calendar;
```

En mi caso, utilicé el resto del código en el `onCreate` de la siguiente manera:

```
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Button boton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(Calendario.this, Year, Month, Day);
            datePickerDialog.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Seleccione fecha de pedido");

            Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            datePickerDialog.setMinDate(minDate);

            Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Month + 3);
            datePickerDialog.setMaxDate(maxDate);

            for (Calendar loopdate = minDate; minDate.before(maxDate); minDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1), loopdate = minDate) {
                int dayOfWeek = loopdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                    Calendar[] disabledDays = new Calendar[1];
                    disabledDays[0] = loopdate;
                    datePickerDialog.setDisabledDays(disabledDays);
                }
            }
            datePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
        }
    });
```

Lo que hemos realizado es crear un `DatePickerDialog` el cual limitamos a no mostrar los días que le hemos suministrado en `if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY)` si deseas excluir mas días, debes hacerlo en ese if.

Ademas de esto, he puesto una condicion de que solo se muestren los 3 siguientes meses para hacer pedidos, este apartado es:

```
            Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Month + 3);
```

puedes editarlo a tu gusto, o ignorarlo borrandolo.

Espero que esto te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Trate de utilizar tu código pero mi Calendar view lo aplique de una forma, de todas formas encontre una solucion parecida, que funciona.. Es agregar una condición que al seleccionar cualquier fecha del domingo deshabilite los botones de enviar el pedido para que asi no interfiera en la aplicacion, un hechizo simple pero inquebrantable!!. Lo realice añadiendo esta lineas de código en la parte de programacion del CalendarVIew, por si a alguien le sirve:
lo dejo abajo como respuesta: